# timing probability

Tags: probability

Two students give themselves an appointment between 1p.m. and 3p.m. They both agree that the first person who arrives should leave after having waited for 40minutes. What is the probability that the appointment isn't going to take place.

I'll be very glad to have a detailed explanation thanks.

Comment: I relish this type of question but you need to give some indication of what you've tried already. You've just joined and it seems like you're after a freebie assignment solution.

Comment: i think between 1p.m and 3p.m is 2hrs that is 120mins, and 40mins out of this 120mins gives a probability of 1/3 that the appointment will hold and therefore a probability of 2/3 that it wouldn't hold. But i still have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

This question is the same as the following question :

When we choose two values $x,y$ in $[0,120]$ on the number line, find the probability that $x,y$ satisfy
$$|x-y|\le 40.$$

Hence, we have 
$$|x-y|\le 40\iff -40\le x-y\le 40\iff x-40\le y\le x+40.$$

Considering the region with $xy$-coordinates, and noting that $0\le x\le 120,0\le y\le 120, $we know the answer is
$$\frac{120\times 120 -(1/2)\times (120-80)\times 80\times 2}{120\times 120}=\frac 59.$$

You'll know this by drawing a $120\times 120$ square, and two lines $y=x\pm 40.$

**P.S.** This is called [geometric probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_probability).

Comment: thanks alot. i've got it but i still don't understand the numerator of your final expression @mathlove

Comment: OK. please draw the diagram. Four points $(0,0),(120,0),(120,120),(0,120)$. This is a square. Then, draw two lines $y=x\pm 40.$ Do you know the meaning of $x-40\le y\le x+40$?

Comment: yes i do, inequality boundaries. when the 2lines are drawn the required region is between them

Comment: Nice! so, the region we consider is the rigion in the square which satisfies the inequality. You'll find the region like a hexagon. The answer is (the area of the hexagon)/(the area of the square). By the way, I was a bit wrong. I edited it.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: when calculating i get 7/9 instead of what you have

Comment: I don't think so. What is the area of one triangle at the corner of the square? is it $3200$?

Comment: yes it is. you then have to edit the numerator i.e. the base and height of the triangle are both 40 not 80 as you wrote

Comment: No. you may be thinking that $40\times 80=3200$? No, we have to multiply $1/2$. I suspect you think the length of the base of the triangle is $40$. The correct answer is the height is $80$ and the base is also $80$. be careful. so, the area of the triangle is $(1/2)\times 80\times 80=3200.$

Comment: ok i think i get it now

Comment: Again, you are welcome.